# Can't telnet K8S ClientIP service from all nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, rancher

I'm struggling with K8S networking when I try to expose a service within a cluster. In particular I need to deploy a private container registry (through K8S) and exposing it as clusterIP service.

In order to do this I've followed this [article](https://medium.com/@jmarhee/deploying-a-docker-registry-with-persistent-storage-and-local-only-access-on-your-kubernetes-1c6470d3611c)

For the moment I don't need any particular volume, I just want to expose the service inside the cluster.

This is the POD yml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: registry
  labels:
    app: registry
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - name: registry
    image: registry:2
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    ports:
      - containerPort: 5000
```

While this is my service file:

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: registry
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    app: registry
  ports:
    - port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
```

Both objects are created through `kubectl create -f <FILE_NAME>`

Those are my exposed services

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.43.0.1       <none>        443/TCP    55m
registry     ClusterIP   10.43.198.164   <none>        5000/TCP   10m
```

While this is my services description list

```
Name:              kubernetes
Namespace:         default
Labels:            component=apiserver
                   provider=kubernetes
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          <none>
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.43.0.1
Port:              https  443/TCP
TargetPort:        6443/TCP
Endpoints:         172.31.5.173:6443
Session Affinity:  ClientIP
Events:            <none>


Name:              registry
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=registry
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.43.198.164
Port:              <unset>  5000/TCP
TargetPort:        5000/TCP
Endpoints:         10.42.1.4:5000
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

When I run `telnet 10.43.198.164 5000` in the same node where the pod is deployed everything is working fine, while if I launch it in another node (it's a 2 node cluster), the command remain appended.

Nodes are AWS ec2 instances with CentOS 7

Kubernetes is under version 1.8.3, deployed through RANCHER RKE

I found several issues for this problem, but nothing that can help me investigating the problem.

Here you can find used RKE config file for instantiating the cluster

```
#{{ ansible_managed }}

nodes:
  - address: node1
    user: user
    role: [controlplane,worker,etcd]
    ssh_key_path: path
  - address: node2
    user: user
    role: [worker]
    ssh_key_path: path

ignore_docker_version: false

kubernetes_version: v1.10.1
network:
  plugin:flannel
```

Any help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that problem is related to docker registry. Looks like it's on network layer.

Debug questions:

- What CNI plugin do you use?
- Can you reach pod directly (`telnet 10.42.1.4 5000`)?
- Are your nodes (`kubectl get nodes`) and system pods (`kubectl -n kube-system get pods`) ready?

Comment: Hi Igor, 
1- I'm using FLANNEL as CNI
2- POD is reacheable directly only from the node where is executed
3- kubectl get nodes gives status ready for both nodes same for system pods (sorry output length doesn't fit in comment size).

Comment: I don't have experience with Flannel but I know that it uses native network. Maybe you have to update AWS's Security Group to add required ip/ports.

Comment: Unfortunately port 5000 is already added as exception for inbound traffic in both nodes. I also add that if I telnet the other service (kubernetes) I'm able to interrogate it (telnet) from both nodes.

Comment: @luke035 are you using flannel or canal? Could you share you rke config file with masked out IPs? Also where are you running the telent command? Do you start a container/pod on the different nodes? Did you open the VXLAN port for flannel?

Comment: Hi @leodotcloud, I'm using flannel. Please find the rake config file in the opening post. Telnet is run on both node, when it's launched from the node where the pod is deployed everything works as expected, but when I launch it in the other node the cluster ip is not visible. No I didn't explicitly opened VXLAN port for flannel, is something I should put in RKE config?

Comment: @luke035 you need to configure your security groups to open the VXLAN ports, nothing to be done in RKE config.

Comment: @leodotcloud wow great! Can you link me any instruction guide to do so?

Comment: @luke035 Does this help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html ?

Comment: Also you can see the ports here: https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/single-node-install/

Comment: @leodotcloud great thanks! Unfortunately my cluster went down (it was composed by spot instances). I have to "redo" everything, and I'll let you know